# XenServer - Recovering VM

Tags: xenserver, data-recovery

After googling all day I have had no luck, so I hope someone on here can assist me.

I setup my XenServer, created a ubuntu VM, then placed my itunes library (300gb+) onto the system.  After this, I then go to install another VM, after failing I restart the server although during restart we had a powercut.

When the power came back on initially my VM wasn't working, (said something about a mkdir failing) - So I found this may be over came by restarting again - Then the problem got worse as the server now wont boot fully.

So essentially I have my itunes library sitting on the hard drive, which I can access from my main PC (in ubuntu) yet I am unable to find the files.

**Is there any way of recovering the files before reinstalling or during reinstalling *without* being able to previously access the server.**

Comment: "server now wont boot fully" - you mean the VM or XenServer? What's on the screen?

Comment: The XenServer, sorry - Just appears with the Citrix XenServer "splash" screen and doesn't progress

Comment: If you press ESC does something come up?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen on pressing ESC, instantly or after a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check your ram on your server. Next boot the server with a livecd. I like the suse install DVD bc it has good support for lvm. Boot into it and use pvscan and vgscan to look for the storage repository holding your vhd files.  See here http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html?m=1 once you find the SR with your vhd files. Copy the one with the correct file size elsewhere. Now you can open your vhd and get your files back

Comment: Thanks wasn't a ram issue but I managed to retrieve the files.  Thanks again!